# DNS problem with OpenVPN connection

Tags: openvpn

I'm having a problem with a VPN connection using OpenVPN on Ubuntu 22.04. When I connect to my VPN Server I can access my devices in my private network by IP Address, but I can't access by name resolution (my connection is consulting the DNS of my provider, not my private DNS). Analyzing the connection I could see that my VPN Server is providing the IP Address for my device and the IP Address of my private DNS server, which is being  put in the file `/run/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf`, but the name resolution of internal addresses isn't working.

Searching on the Internet, somebody said I have to install `openvpn-systemd-resolved` to solve this problem. I installed, but I couldn't find how to configure it.

How can I configure `openvpn-systemd-resolved` in this situation?

Comment: This is a common problem when going through a VPN.  If you can ping the outside world (8.8.8.8 for example), set up your VPN client to use the VPN provider's DNS.  This is the safer and more reliable way to go.  PIA is inexpensive, very reliable and has a GUI client that integrates perfectly in current distros of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1465806/1684306

Comment: @mpboden Thank you for your help, it's working. But I have another problem. I have 2 domains in my private network but with this configuration, only one of them can be resolved by my internal DNS. Is there any way to make this other domain to be resolved by my internal DNS, when I'm connected with my VPN?