# Configuring the DNS client

Tags: resolv.conf, ifconfig

I use WiFi to connect my Ubuntu os running on a Macbook Air to my router. In order to send traffic, I went to configure its network interface by entering the code:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I then run `ifconfig wlp3s0` to see if the code has taken effect, and it has. However, the bottom of my screen says

```
        RX packets 18736  bytes 14993908 (14.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 16760
        TX packets 10419  bytes 1679150 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

What does the "device interrupt 18" mean and what are its implications?

Then, I would proceed to putting the DNS related configuration in place by specifying the DNS cache-only service details in the etc resolv.conf file by entering this code:

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

At first, I got this response that stated,

> this file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.

The system didn't allow me to make any changes to the IP address from the terminal. In fact, when I pressed the down and up key on my keyboard in the terminal to get to the IP address and change it, random letters like "A" for down arrow and "B" for up arrow showed up on the terminal. I just proceeded to quit terminal and tried to log back in to reenter the code and try again but now when I enter the command above, I get a message that says,

> "E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name "/run/systemd/resolve/.stub-resolv.conf.swp" owned by: root"...

...plus some other details such as the date and time when the file was created. I proceeded to use the code:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

to get rid of any unsaved sessions from the sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf, and now when I try to run the sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf command, I get a different message that states:

> #Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc) resolver (3) generated by resolvconf (8)
>
> #DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND-- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
>
> #127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
>
> #run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

What should I do here? I deeply appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Do what the messages say. Read `man resolv.conf resolver resolvconf`. Do: `systemd-resolve --status`. Also read `man systemd-resolv systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: @waltinator When I do the `systemd-resolve --status` I get a response that says, `systemd-resolve: command not found` and when I enter `man systemd-resolv systemd-dnsmasq` I get a response that says `no manual entry for systemd-resolv `No manual entry for systemd-dnsmasq. Is it that my system is not properly configured? I also don't understand what the "device interrupt 18" means.

Comment: On a side note: if you're not familiar with using vim yet, you should probably use `nano` instead. So something like this would be `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and nano simply uses regular input mode, arrow keys to move the cursor. To save the file, press CTRL+o (o for overwrite) and CTRL+x to exit nano. And these shortcuts should be listed at the bottom of the terminal.

Comment: When it talks about a swap file, you can typically just ignore or overwrite it unless there was some important changes you needed to recover. Since you exited the terminal instead of saving a copy before exiting vim, the system is providing a backup option for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DNS resolver associated with a network interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462604/what-is-dns-resolver-associated-with-a-network-interface)

Comment: You can either edit the [existing systemd file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/resolved.conf.5.html#options) `sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` or you can simply delete the `/etc/resolv.conf` and replace it with a static, text file [as described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1462613). I would probably recommend editing the existing systemd file first (the preferred method) and if you decide later you want to replace `/etc/resolv.conf` you can. Under the `[Resolve]` section, make sure `DNS=` is uncommented and add the DNS server address here.

Comment: @mchid Thank you so much for your help!! This is awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either edit [the existing systemd file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/resolved.conf.5.html#options):

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

<sub>under the `[Resolve]` section, make sure `DNS=` is uncommented and add the DNS server address here</sub>

or you can simply delete `/etc/resolv.conf` and replace it with a static, text file as [described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1462613). I would probably recommend editing the existing systemd file first (the preferred method) and if you decide later you want to replace `/etc/resolv.conf` you can.